Reduce Redshift Query Cost
Intro
I am currentry running a query that was reported, by the DataEng team, to be highly resource consuming.
I need some help to improve it/ reduce its cost.
Case
I have a table (status_history_table) that shows, for all of my customers, their status and a date range that this status is valid. I need a query that returns, daily, how many customers have changed their status and how much of them didnt changed it.
Only the last 365 days of data are needed.
status_history_table example:



user_id
status
valid_from
valid_to




X
'active'
20240401
20240405


X
'inactive'
20240406
99991231



When we have valid_to as '99991231' it means this is the current status of the customer, i.e, it is valid untill something happens/changes it.
dim_date_table is a dimension table with all dates;



id_date
date_




20240401
2024-04-01


20240402
2024-04-02



This is the current query I am using:
with
    daily_status as (
        select
            h.user_id
            , d.id_date
            , h.status
        from
            status_history_table h
            inner join dim_date_table d
                on d.id_date between h.valid_from and h.valid_to 
                and d.date_ <= current_date
                and d.date_ > current_date - 365
    )

    , lag as (
        select 
            *
            , lag(status,1)over(partition by user_id order by id_date asc) as previous_status
        from
            daily_status
    )

    select 
        id_date
        case
            when previous_status = status_braze then 'No change'
            else 'Changed'
        end as class,
        count(1) as user_qty
    from 
        lag
    group by 
        1,2

There are some more infos that I am extracting for this report, but this query represents the most important logic that is being used.
Any help will be appreciated.
Update1:
This is the real query I am using:
with
    base as (
        select 
            d.date_,
            h.subscription_status as status,
            braze_id
        from 
            curated_data.braze_subscription_history h
            inner join business_layer.dim_date d 
                on d.pk_date between h.valid_from and h.valid_to 
                and d.date_ <= current_date
                and d.date_ > current_date - 365
        where
            h.source = 'PUSH'
            and h.country_code = 'BR'
    ),

    -- ve qual foi o status anterior de cada cliente
    lag as (
        select 
            *,
            lag(status,1)over(partition by braze_id order by date_ asc) as previous_status
        from
            base
    )
    

    select 
        date_
        , case
            when previous_status = status then 'No change'
            else 'Changed'
        end as class,
        count(1) as user_qty
    from 
        lag
    group by 
        1,2

Result of running "explain"
XN HashAggregate  (cost=1000679035081.81..1000679075081.81 rows=8000000 width=78)
  ->  XN Subquery Scan lag  (cost=1000627708182.17..1000668036460.46 rows=1466482847 width=78)
        ->  XN Window  (cost=1000627708182.17..1000649705424.87 rows=1466482847 width=45)
              Partition: h.braze_id
              Order: d.date_
              ->  XN Sort  (cost=1000627708182.17..1000631374389.29 rows=1466482847 width=45)
                    Sort Key: h.braze_id, d.date_
                    ->  XN Network  (cost=7525.05..404438272.74 rows=1466482847 width=45)
                          Distribute
                          ->  XN Nested Loop DS_BCAST_INNER  (cost=7525.05..404438272.74 rows=1466482847 width=45)
                                Join Filter: (("inner".pk_date <= ("outer".valid_to)::bigint) AND ("inner".pk_date >= ("outer".valid_from)::bigint))
                                ->  XN Seq Scan on braze_subscription_history h  (cost=0.00..1472107.32 rows=36159851 width=49)
                                      Filter: (((source)::text = 'PUSH'::text) AND ((country_code)::text = 'BR'::text))
                                ->  XN Materialize  (cost=7525.05..7528.70 rows=365 width=12)
                                      ->  XN Seq Scan on dim_date d  (cost=0.00..224.69 rows=365 width=12)
                                            Filter: ((date_ > '2023-04-09'::date) AND (date_ <= '2024-04-08'::date))
----- Nested Loop Join in the query plan - review the join predicates to avoid Cartesian products -----

DDLS:
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS curated_data.braze_subscription_history
(
    country_code VARCHAR(2)   ENCODE zstd
    ,braze_id VARCHAR(32)   ENCODE zstd
    ,external_id VARCHAR(32)   ENCODE zstd
    ,source VARCHAR(16)   ENCODE zstd
    ,subscription_status VARCHAR(16)   ENCODE zstd
    ,valid_from INTEGER   ENCODE az64
    ,valid_to INTEGER   ENCODE az64
)
DISTSTYLE EVEN


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS business_layer.dim_date
(
    pk_date BIGINT NOT NULL  ENCODE az64
    ,iso_date VARCHAR(40)   ENCODE zstd
    ,"year" VARCHAR(16)   ENCODE zstd
    ,quarter_of_year VARCHAR(8)   ENCODE zstd
    ,month_of_year VARCHAR(8)   ENCODE zstd
    ,date_ DATE   ENCODE az64
    ,year_month VARCHAR(6)   ENCODE zstd
    ,id_date BIGINT   ENCODE az64
)
DISTSTYLE ALL


Try to run your query for a shorter period until it works then run it multiple times till you get data for the year. Maybe you can only get 2, 3 , or 4 months of data a time.

Sidenote: Why this strange idea of going 365 days back? This is mostly incorrect and often done because people do not know about date functions. Usually, it's better to use - interval '1 year'.

Could you share the query plan, using EXPLAIN VERBOSE for this statement? And the DDL for all tables and indexes involved. All in plain text, as an update of your question.

The columns valid_from and 20240405 don't benefit from changing the data types to an integer. Both INT and DATE take 4 bytes. Your current data model is more costly, without any benefits. I would change this, and use the DATE data type. And did you index these columns? If so, a single index on both or two separate indexes?

@FrankHeikens just updated my post with required info

Why do you use a BIGINT for pk_date, but an INT for valid_to and valid_from? This Seq Scan on braze_subscription_history tells me that there is no useful index, not on the dates and not on the country_code and source columns. And as said before, there is no reason to use integers to replace a date and put this date in a dimension table. I would change the data model. And start indexing the fact table curated_data.braze_subscription_history because it's now slow by design.

@FrankHeikens I have created my "*history" table using IDs instead of Dates because I thought this would be faster than querying for actual dates... and as for the indexing I am not used to them, will use this particular case to learn about it better and try to improve performance

The size of an INT and a DATE is exactly the same. But in your current data model you first have to check the dim_date_table before the database can start searching for the real data you're looking for. If your data would be a DATE, you could have skipped that step. About the indexes, set the SORTKEY. See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html for details

What is your SORT key in both tables? Also, Try changing the Dist style for curated_data.braze_subscription_history table, use braze_id as dist key and sort key.

This is a common but thorny problem.  The BETWEEN in the JOIN ON clause is causing a lot of new rows to be created in a loop.  This process is expensive and downstream operations on the this inflated dataset are also affected.  Also data warehouses are optimized for data analysis, not data creation so this type of query are even more expensive on Redshift.
There is a way to attack this to make it much more efficient but it requires a rethinking of how you perform the analysis and for most analytics, but not all.  The performance improvement is astounding but working it out will make your brain hurt.  I did this for a customer and a query that was taking 90 minutes on Redshift and 45 min on a massive EMR cluster was optimized to 16 seconds.  So this really does work.
I wrote a tutorial on doing this optimization here - https://wadevelopment.co/sql_limits_wp.html
The basic idea is to replace the INNER JOIN with a UNION ALL while making some new columns to detect the changes in status.  Then use rolling sums to get the daily statistics.  What I see in your query looks like it should work this way.
I'm happy to answer follow-up questions about this but changing to this approach is a rewrite.

OP's question doesn't really ask any specific question so it would be a stretch if I played a not-an-answer card in a not-a-question thread, but it does sound a bit like you're promoting your services or commenting a hint, not offering an answer.

Could you give an initial idea on how would you approach my problem using your solution ?

Read the tutorial.  It lays out exactly how to approach this class of problem for orders of magnitude faster execution.  Too long of an explanation to rewrite every time this question comes up.

Sure. This will look very much like the tutorial on counting active accounts.  Quick question first - you have 'active' and 'inactive' windows, is there a third state?  Not active or inactive.  Or is inactive just that same as days where id isn't active?

@BillWeiner I actually have 3 states: "default" for an new customer, "active" when a customer accepts our newsletter and "inactive" when they cancel it

Another important question is whether there is the need to merge windows of active for the same user_id.  went active on the 1st, inactive on the 5th, active again on the 6th, and inactive again on the 10th.  Really  should be just one active window from the 1st through the 10th.  If this exists then some data prep might be needed to not over count "changes"

@BillWeiner no, i dont need to merge those situations.. actually, I shouldnt to that. I need to be able to see all changes

You want to lay out a timeline that has every date and what happened on this date - did an id go active or inactive.  This is done by UNIONing the table with itself and your dates table.  Your columns will be date, id, going active, going inactive, ending active and ending inactive.  So each row in your starting table will end up as 2 rows in this timeline plus all the dates from your date table but nothing in for the other columns.  With this timeline you can count up the number of transitions by date and use rolling sums to know how many are in any state at any point in time
